# Warning when building with prefix.pch file

Tags: iphone, zbar-sdk

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'Bar_scan' target in the 'Bar_scan' project
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
# import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
# import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
# import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
# import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
# import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
# import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
# import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
# import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
# import "ZBarSDK.h"
#endif
```

I receive this [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ6ZI.png) by building with prefix.pch file:

> Lexical or preprocessor Issue

What could be the reason?

This is a project that uses [zbar SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/latest/download). Unfortunatly their program is also not working and has exactly the same problem.
And actually it does not see any of my frameworks.
Have somebody any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ! after `#endif` so use:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
# import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
# import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
# import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
# import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
# import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
# import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
# import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
# import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
# import "ZBarSDK.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was not the mistake. I've made it only hear, and actually the problem is here: # import <Foundation/Foundation.h> - 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found